# Feasibility of using multi master Kubernetes cluster architecture

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline using Kubernetes and Jenkins. In my application I have 25 Micro services. And need to deploy it for 5 different clients. The microservice code is unique. But configuration for each client is different.

So here I am configuring Spring cloud config server with 5 different Profiles/Configuration. And When I am building Docker images, I will define which is the active config server profile by adding active profile in Docker file. So from 25 microservices I am building 25 * 5 number of Docker images and deploying that. So total 125 microservices I need to deploy in Kubernetes cluster.  And these microservice are calling from my Angular 2 front end application.

Here when I am considering the performance of application and speed of response, the single master is enough of this application architecture? Or Should I definitely need to use the multi master Kubernetes cluster? How I can manage this application?

I am new to these cloud and CI/CD pipeline architecture tasks. So I have confusion related with designing of workflow. If single master is enough, then I can continue with current. Otherwise I need to implement the multi master Kubernetes HA cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of the application and/or the speed do not depend on the number of master nodes. It resolves High Availability issues, but not performance. Now, you should still consider having at least 3 masters for this implementation you are working on. If the master goes down, your cluster is useless.

In Kubernetes, the master gets the API calls and acts upon them, by setting the desired state of the cluster to the current state. But in the end that's the nodes (slaves) doing the heavy work. So your performance issues will depend mostly, if not exclusively, on your nodes. If you have enough memory and CPU, you should be fine.

Comment: OK. I understood your point. Thank you. But I have doubt in your last statement. How we can analyze the amount of memory and how much CPU need for  our POD at node level ? . If I am launched EC2 machine as a Worker Machine/Node , Then How I can distribute VMs total RAM capacity among the Pods for deployment? Can you clarify the idea about architecturing on memory base at node level?

Comment: That is going to depend on your application. You need to define what is the consumption in terms of resources (CPU and memory) of your apps. Once defined that you can decide what machine type to choose, and how many. I would recommend you to define also resource requests and limits for each pod, as by default a pod can use all the CPU and memory of its node, so if something goes wrong, it can starve other pods. **I would elaborate more, but I don't have enough characters.**

Comment: Can you append your comment below please? I am not seeing chat option here.

Comment: I said pretty much everything. I  meant I would add examples and more text, if would have more room, but the backbone is said above. I'll add this. Don't see the cluster as separate VMs with certain amount of CPU and memory each (unless you have 1 super pod that consumes A LOT), but see it as one. Then setting resource requests and limits you will provision the desired resource to each pod.

Answer (score 1):

Multi master sounds like a good idea for HA.

You could also look at using [Helm](https://www.helm.sh/) which lets you configure microservices in a per installation basis so that you don't have to keep re-releasing docker images each time to configure a new environment. You can then inject the helm configuration into, say, a `ConfigMap` that mounts the content as an `application.yml` so that Spring Boot automatically loads the settings